# Handle a selected value in rails (before submit)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redmine

I'm new in rails and I want retrieve a selected value to a field in order to adapt an other field in the same form.

```
<% if @issue.safe_attribute? 'tracker_id' %>
  <p><%= f.select :tracker_id, @issue.project.trackers.collect {|t| [t.name, t.id]}, {:required => true},
                  :onchange => "updateIssueFrom('#{escape_javascript project_issue_form_path(@project, :id => @issue, :format => 'js')}')" %></p>
<% end %>

<% if @issue.safe_attribute? 'parent_issue_id' %>
<p id="parent_issue"><%= f.text_field :parent_issue_id, :size => 10, :required => @issue.required_parent_issue_id?(*the tracker_id selected*) %></p>
<% end %>
```

How to handle the value *the tracker_id selected* ?

Comment: You have to do it with javascript - once html got to the browser, your server has no right to knwo what is being selected etc until the form is submitted, so rails is not a way to go here (it is server-side only). Most likely you'll need to use AJAX here as well to communicate server about the change.

Comment: Please read about the client-server-principle.